# 2012 Audi Q5 P2177 Code "System Too Lean"

Tags: audi, cel, lean

My wife's 2012 Audi Q5 has recently popped its check-engine light, and my scan tool reports:

- "P2177 SAE System Too Lean Off Idle Bank 1"

She says that it appears to run & drive without issues and in the 30-min drive I took it on it seemed to behave fine to me, and it doesn't sound any different to before when idling or revving while standing still.

I have put 2 bottles of SeaFoam fuel injector cleaner thru it over the last week, but this doesn't appear to have made any difference - I can clear the code and it just comes back again.

What are the next most likely culprits for me to start checking?
Fuel filter? Fuel pump?
Any ideas most welcome ...